# AWSの無料枠について

Tags: aws

AWSでアカウントを作成したときの12ヶ月の無料枠についてわからない箇所があったのでお聞きしたいです。

AWS上でNVIDIAのDIGITSを使用したいと思い検索したところ、NVIDIAがDIGITSを使えるセットを置いていました。
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01LZN28VD

これを使おうと思ったのですが、AWSを使用したときの料金として1.インスタンス価格,2.ストレージ価格,3.データ通信量による価格の合計が支払う金額だと認識しております。
AWSのアカウントを作成したときの無料枠は利用が750H以内のときとあったのでインスタンス価格は対象になることは理解できますが、ストレージとデータ通信量による課金は無料枠ではどのように扱われるのでしょうか？
無料枠ではストレージの制限がある？

自分のそもそもの理解が間違っていたら申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

AWS EC2は機能に応じて[様々なインスタンスタイプ](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/ec2/instance-types/)が用意されています。[GPUを使えるインスタンスタイプ](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/ec2/instance-types/#gpu)はP2及びG2となっています。一方、[無料枠](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/free/)で利用可能なのはGPUの使えないt2.microだけです。
というわけで無理です。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。無料枠がt2.microのみであることが理解できました。今回はp2 , g2で行おうと思います。
ついでの質問で申し訳ないのですが、別使用でt2.microの無料枠を使用する場合、ストレージがEBSとあるのですが、そちらのストレージの価格は無料にならないという認識でよいのでしょうか？

Comment: @Chironeko さん、無料枠のリンク先を読まれていないのでしょうか？

Comment: すみませんでした。インスタンスの使用量と明記してありました。

Comment: @Chironeko さん、そうではなくEBSにも無料枠が用意されています。リンク先をよく読んで出直してください。